# Executing a function on a specific thread in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++14

I have a class which has some of its functions thread-safe.

```
class A 
{
    public:
    // Thread Safe class B
    B foo;
    // Thread specific class C
    C bar;

    void somefunc()
    {
        // uses foo and bar
    }
}

class C
{
    public:
    C()
    {
        m_id = std::this_thread::get_id();
    }

    // id of the thread which created the class
    std::thread::id m_id;
}
```

class A can be set on different threads. As class C is thread-specific I want to run `somefun` from the thread `m_id`.

So I was thinking of executing somefun by submitting somefun to the thread identified by m_id.

**The main question is can I run a particular function on a live thread given that I know the thread id of the thread**?

Comment: Not very clear, as C is both a type and a variable of type bar... please give a [mcve]

Comment: Sorry I messed up while typing the question

Comment: Could you show us how do you create threads and how they share the instance of `A`?

Comment: Still vague. Is A thread safe? How does the thread have an object of A? You've made you example so abstract that it's hard to follow. What is the bigger picture?

Comment: Well, you wrote whatever function is already running in that thread. So write a way to tell that function to call `somefunc`

Comment: `thread_local C bar;` Makes sure that `bar` is thread specific.

Comment: So just compare the current thread id with the stored one and run `somefunc` only if they are equal.

Comment: @DanielLangr, in this case, it won't run if current thread id is not m_id. What, I want is if it is not, then submit the function to be run on the thread with id m_id

Comment: For all intents and purposes, the thread *is* the function. This approach doesn't make a lot of sense. `std::thread` is pretty lightweight. Other than dropping in an assembly module that could re-assign the instruction pointer for the desired thread, I don't see any way to do this and certainly not anything that would be portable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was thinking of executing somefun by submitting somefun to the thread identified by `m_id`.

That is not how threads work in general. You can't ask just any thread to stop what it is doing and call a certain function. The only way that it makes sense to submit anything to a thread is if the thread is already running code that is designed to accept the submission and, that knows what to do with it.

You could write a thread that loops forever, and on each iteration it waits to consume a `std::function<...>` object from a blocking queue, and then it calls the object. Then, some other thread could "submit" `std::function<...>` objects to the thread by putting them in the queue.

Comment: I was about to write up the same approach, though in this case it might make more sense to use a `map` using the desired thread id as the key and the `function` as the value. My feeling is that all of this silliness is going to consume more time than just firing off a new thread, but that's OP's issue, not yours.

Comment: Yes, this will very well work. Do you have any idea instead of busy waiting

Comment: @pr0py_s, I don't have time to write or find an example for this, but when the client "submits" a function object, it could get back a [_Future_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises) object. The Future object would contain a mutex and a condition variable, it would have a method named `complete()` that is called by the worker thread to signal the condition after the submitted function returns, and it would have a method named `get()` or `await()` that is called by the client to wait for the event.  It also could hold the value returned by the submitted function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [boost::asio::io_service](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service.html).

A function (or work) posted on a thread will be executed on a different thread (on which `run()` member function of io_service is called).

A Rough Example:

```
#include <boost/asio/io_service.hpp>

boost::asio::io_service ios_;

void func(void)
{
    std::cout << "Executing work: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
}

// Thread 1
ios_.run();

// Thread 2
std::cout << "Posting work: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
ios_.post(func);

ios_.port([] () {
    std::cout << "Lambda" << std::endl;
});
```

Comment: Good idea, but the OP wants the function to be called by a _specific_ other thread, not by whatever pool worker happens to be available.